# Error code 1054 Unknown column "Notification" in "field list" when creating a Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I hope someone can help as I am going crazy over this. I am learning how to set up triggers. I am working in MySQL workbench and I have two tables: Product2 and Notifications. The trigger is to notify the sales department if a record inserted into the Products2 table has a SellPrice that is equal to or less than the BuyPrice.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ProductSellPriceUpdateCheck 
    AFTER UPDATE  
    ON Products2 FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.SellPrice <= NEW.BuyPrice THEN
        INSERT INTO Notifications(Notification,DateTime) 
        VALUES(CONCAT(NEW.ProductID,' was updated with a SellPrice of ', NEW.SellPrice,' which is the same or less than the BuyPrice'), NOW()); 
    END IF;
    END;
DELIMITER ;
```

This code was accepted with no problems. However, when I go to insert a new record into the products table to test this:

```
INSERT INTO Products2 (ProductID, ProductName, BuyPrice, SellPrice, NumberOfItems) VALUES ('P7', 'product p7', 40.00, 40.00, 100);
```

I get an error

> 1054. Unknown column 'Notification' in 'field list'.

I know this is related to the trigger somehow because I can drop the trigger and run the insert and it works just fine. Plus, the only column called 'Notification' is in the Notifications table not in the `Products2` table. This Notification column is not the primary key of the `Notifications` table and is a `VARCHAR(255)`. My message to be placed into the Notifications column is not that many characters so I don't believe that is a problem.

I would appreciate any insight as to what I am doing wrong. Like I said, I'm new to this and although I am enjoying it greatly, it can be a bit frustrating.

---I was so frustrated when I put up this question that I failed to realize I put up the AFTER UPDATE syntax and not the AFTER INSERT. Here is the AFTER INSERT but I want to mention that I have the same problem trying to add, change, or delete values.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ProductSellPriceInsertCheck
AFTER INSERT
ON Products2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF New.SellPrice <= New.BuyPrice
THEN INSERT INTO Notifications (Notifaction, DateTime) VALUES (CONCAT('A sellPrice same or less than the BuyPrice was inserted for ProductID', New.ProductID), NOW());
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Are there any other triggers invoked by this action? E.g. an INSERT trigger on the `Notifications` table?

Comment: show table `Notifications` structure. This does not look right `INSERT INTO Notifications(Notification,DateTime) ...`

Comment: An UPDATE trigger won't fire on an insert..so there may be an insert trigger on product2.

Comment: @BillKarwin There are no other INSERT triggers but there are two more that were created at the same time: AFTER UPDATE which notifies if an updated SellPrice has been changed to an amount that is less than or equal to the BuyPrice and AFTER DELETE which notifies when a record from the Products2 table has been deleted.

Comment: @T.S. This is the Notifications table that was created to hold the trigger values: CREATE TABLE Notifications (NotificationID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, Notification VARCHAR(255), DateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(NotificationID)); All of the syntax I have shown in my question is from a lesson from the Meta Data Engineer Course Certificate.

Comment: @P.Salmon You are right!  I just realized that I put the wrong trigger up there. There are three triggers that were created: AFTER INSERT, AFTER UPDATE, AND AFTER DELETE. I was so frustrated that I put up the AFTER UPDATE trigger instead of AFTER INSERT. I'm going to try to edit my comment so I can add the INSERT INTO syntax.

Comment: 'INSERT INTO Notifications (Notifaction' IS wrongly spelled but is that a typo here or in the reported error?

Comment: 1. all these info pieces you should add to the question. We don't need to dig it. 2. Check your spellings.. I mean, that names of identifiers are identical everywhere

Comment: @P.Salmon That was it. I was looking at this way too long and just didn't see it. I will be a lot more careful in the future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create trigger ProductSellPriceUpdateCheck after Update on Products for each row 
begin 
if new.sellprice <= old.buyprice then insert into Notifications(Notification, DateTime) values (concat(old.ProductID,' was updated with a SellPrice of ',new.SellPrice,' which is the same or less than the', old.BuyPrice), NOW());
end if; 
end //
```

```
UPDATE Products SET sellprice = 60 WHERE productid = "P6";
```